# How to get Platform details by Usage operation (RunInstances). AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, operating-system

On this link [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/billing-info-fields.html#billing-info] you can see info, that usage operation according to operation system. But there are just table with few examples, so I do not want to "hard code" this info.
Maybe somebody knows some API or CLI request, how to get this?
Thank you in advance

I have already tried to find solution here (on StackOverflow), also i tried to use cli request: `aws ec2 describe-images`, with some filters. But i can be stupid, and maybe this cli request can help me.

Answer (score 1):

To find the latest SDK examples for this AWS Service, look at the AWS Code Library. You will find many code examples in different programming languages. For example, here you will see how to describe an EC2 instance in various programming languages:

[image]

See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/ec2_code_examples_actions.html

For each code example in the Code Lib - you will find a link back to Github where you will find all the necessary information to setup your development environment in order to successfully run the example.